# Exporting all selected RDLC reports into one word/excel/PDF document

Tags: rdlc, reportviewer, export-to-word

Currently I am working on a application in which a user can export a **RLDC** report to Word, PDF, Excel by using report viewer's default exporting options. In a report wizard, users are allowed to select multiple reports. Report viewer by default render a single report at a time and exporting option is only limited to that report only. Is there any option from report viewer to export all the selected reports at a time on a single Word/excel or PDF?? If no, then what can I do to implement that requirement? Seeking for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [This Example](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/888937/RDLC-Export-Directly-to-Word-Excel-or-PDF-from-Cod) customizing your export in this way:

```
 var x = ReportViewer.LocalReport.ListRenderingExtensions();
        RenderingExtension render_ = null;

        var obj = (sender as Button);

        switch (obj.Tag.ToString())
        {
            case "word":
                render_ = x[5];
                break;
            case "excel":
                render_ = x[1];
                break;
            case "pdf":
                render_ = x[3];
                break;
        }
```